# File upload from Browser to Jersey (server)client to Jersey Server

Tags: kotlin, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0, dropwizard, jersey-client

**Background**

I have two services. *Service A* is exposed to the outside world and *Service B* is invoked by *Service A*. All of these services are dropwizard services. The feature I am trying to implement is to upload a file from frontend which is uploaded to *Service A* which handles auth. The same request as is should be transferred to *Service B*. *Service B* should get the file and save it to disk after compression and thumbnail creation.

I have tested both the services *individually* using postman and they are able to receive the file as InputStream and the content disposition.

**Problem**

The problem I am facing is when I want to pass the file in the formData from *Service A* to *Service B*.

Here is the code in *Service A* that sends the form data to *Service B*.

```
@POST
@Timed
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
fun create(
        @Auth user: AuthUser,
        @FormDataParam("file") file: InputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") fileDetail: FormDataContentDisposition,
        @FormDataParam("file") body: FormDataBodyPart,
        @PathParam("res_id") articleId: String): Response {
    val multiPart = FormDataMultiPart()
    multiPart.bodyPart(body)
    val target = this.client.target("http://localhost:8082/file/create?res_id=1")
    val response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.mediaType), Response::class.java)
    Response.status(response.status).entity(response.entity).build()
}
```

Here is the code in *Service B* that receives it.

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
fun create(
        @FormDataParam("file") file: InputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") fileDetail: FormDataContentDisposition,
        @QueryParam("res_id") resId: String): Response {
    resourceLogger.info("Res id in media create $resId")
    upload_file(file, fileDetail)
    return Response.status(201).entity(mapOf("success" to true)).build()
}
```

The request is reaching *Service A* and is sent to *Service B*. But *Service B* is responding with 400. No logs or stack trace. Couldn't figure out what is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Created a new FormDataBodyPart object with the input stream converted to byte array and same file content disposition. Didn't work. Same 400.

Comment: Check this [working example](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/f54d2050b3946b2bdc1cb8f94c01f3f0). You need Jersey Test Framework dependency to run it.

Comment: So did you figure it out?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha What I figured out is jersey client created by dropwizard is the issue. When I create a new client and register MultiPartFeature, it works. But when I use the client created by dropwizard in Application class, it doesn't work. Others also reported that. Take a look at this google groups thread. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/WeLt4J_dIqs

Comment: If DW uses a different connector from the default one, it may be the problem. Some connectors are unable to change the header. So yoh have to manually build the Boundary.